# Transform JSON in the fly in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with data below:

| DAY | SCORE | V3_SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-19 | { "key_value": [ { "key": "GGT1", "value": "0.9311" }, { "key": "GGT6", "value": "0.8491" }, { "key": "GGT9", "value": "0.8581" } ] } | { "key_value": [ { "key": "93", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "94", "value": "LOW" }, { "key": "80", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "82", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "97", "value": "HIGH" } ] } |

Now I have to create new table like this:

| DAY | SCORE | V3_SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-19 | {"GGT1": "0.9311","GGT6": "0.8491","GGT9": "0.8581"} | { "93": "HIGH", "94": "LOW", "80": "HIGH", "82":"HIGH","97": "HIGH" } |

I am using query like this:

```
WITH JsonData AS (
  SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(SCORE):key_value AS kv
  FROM test_json
)

SELECT
    OBJECT_AGG(PARSE_JSON(j.value):key, PARSE_JSON(j.value):value) as SCORE
FROM JsonData,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => kv) AS j
```

And this gives me a correct result for one column, but when I am started to add second column, like this:

```
WITH JsonData AS (
  SELECT
    PARSE_JSON(SCORE):key_value AS kv,
    PARSE_JSON(V3_SCORE):key_value AS kv3
  FROM test_json
)

SELECT
    OBJECT_AGG(PARSE_JSON(j.value):key, PARSE_JSON(j.value):value) as SCORE,
    OBJECT_AGG(PARSE_JSON(k.value):key, PARSE_JSON(k.value):value) as V3_SCORE
FROM JsonData,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => kv) AS j,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => kv3) AS k
```

This is resulting with error regarding duplicate keys. How I should process with this, I have about 5 or 6 columns to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Each column could be processed separately and joined based on day column(assuming it is unique):

```
WITH score AS (
  SELECT day, OBJECT_AGG(j.value:key, j.value:value) as SCORE
  FROM test_json AS tj
  ,LATERAL FLATTEN(input => TRY_PARSE_JSON(tj.SCORE), path=>'key_value') AS j
  GROUP BY day
), v3_score AS (
  SELECT day, OBJECT_AGG(j.value:key, j.value:value) as v3_SCORE
  FROM test_json AS tj
  ,LATERAL FLATTEN(input => TRY_PARSE_JSON(tj.V3_SCORE), path=>'key_value') AS j
  GROUP BY day
)
SELECT s.day, s.score, v3s.v3_score
FROM score AS s
LEFT JOIN v3_score AS v3s
  ON s.day = v3s.day;
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_json(DAY DATE, SCORE TEXT, V3_SCORE TEXT)
AS
SELECT '2023-09-19', '{ "key_value": [ { "key": "GGT1", "value": "0.9311" }, { "key": "GGT6", "value": "0.8491" }, { "key": "GGT9", "value": "0.8581" } ] }','{ "key_value": [ { "key": "93", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "94", "value": "LOW" }, { "key": "80", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "82", "value": "HIGH" }, { "key": "97", "value": "HIGH" } ] }';
```

Output:

[image]